# Appended Element Inside show.bs.modal didn't Get Overwritten by .html at Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The situation is after I click button that will show modal, it will run an on click event that has 2 jquery inside:

1. **.html** to *modal-body* class
2. **('show.bs.modal')** event which contains **.append** to *modal-body* class

**HTML(button)**

```
     <button class="btn btn-default view_detail" data-toggle = "modal" data-target="#transactionDetailModal">Detail</button>
```

**Same HTML(Modal)**

```
     <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="transactionDetailModal" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

              <!-- Modal content-->
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Selling Report</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">

                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
              </div>

         </div>
     </div>
```

**JS**

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.view_detail').on('click',function(event){

             $('.modal-body').html('<p>.html element</p>');

             $('#transactionDetailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                 $('.modal-body').append('<p>.append element</p>');
             });
         });

     });
```

What happened is if I click the button once, it seems working fine(This is result that I wanted) :

**First click**
[image]

But after that first click, the appended element keep appearing eventhough I think it will get overwritten by .html

**Second click**
[image]

And it keep increasing

**Third click**
[image]

What I want is that the **.append** to got overwritten everytime the modal button is clicked(Just like the first click picture). If I put the **.append** outside the **('show.bs.modal')** it will run fine without showing the previously appended element over and over again everytime I click the button.

**JS**

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.view_detail').on('click',function(event){

             $('.modal-body').html('<p>.html element</p>');

             //I moved this one out from show bs modal below
             $('.modal-body').append('<p>.append element</p>');

             $('#transactionDetailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

             });
         });

     });
```

The JS code above fixed the keep appearing appended element problem.

But why did that happened? I thought for sure that the appended element will get overwritten cause everytime I click the button it will run .html which means that all the elements inside of *modal-body* class will get overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

('show.bs.modal') event will be triggered every time when the modal is shown. The function(given below) you have written earlier will be executed separately every time when the  modal is shown and the html function over writes the code separately.

```
  $('#transactionDetailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $('.modal-body').append('<p>.append element</p>');
  });
```

This function will be triggered separately and not in the click of the ('.view_detail') button.

The ('show.bs.modal') event can be removed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.view_detail').on('click',function(event){

         $('.modal-body').html('<p>.html element</p>');

         $('.modal-body').append('<p>.append element</p>');

       });
     });
 });
```

OR you can trigger that in single function as given below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#transactionDetailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

         $('.modal-body').html('<p>.html element</p>');

         $('.modal-body').append('<p>.append element</p>');
     });

 });
```

Use any one function to eliminate the issue.

Comment: Hmm correct me if I'm wrong ok, I get that it's asynchronous, but in the end it still makes one html code right?  Both the ('show.bs.modal') or the non ('show.bs.modal') method, after the first click, will resulted in exactly the same HTML code, but my question is why the appended element didn't get overwritten by the .html element? I mean the resulted html code is just as same  after the first click for both method, so I thought for sure the .html will wipe the modal-body everytime the button is clicked.

Comment: Actually you are writing two functions. First function (.view-details).on('click') executes in the button click. Then next function ('show.bs.modal') executes only when the modal is shown. In this scenario, the button click clears the html and creates new html when the button is clicked and again after the modal is shown, the append function is executed and appends the ".append-element" each time.

Comment: What I get from you is that both of the function resulted in two separate  HTML? one for .html and one for .append, which is why .html can't affect .append inside ('show.bs.modal') ,correct me if I'm wrong, if that's the case, why if I add $('.modal-body').html(''); inside the ('show.bs.modal'), it will resulted in the .html element erased?(The ".html elements" sentence)

Comment: Yeah you are correct. You can write only one function eliminating that click function.    ` $(document).ready(function(){ $('#transactionDetailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        $('.modal-body').html('<p>.html element</p>');
        $('.modal-body').append('<p>.append element</p>');
  }); }); ` This function is enough to do so, but it happens only when the modal is shown and not at the time of click.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

```
 $('#transactionDetailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $('#transactionDetailModal p').length ? $('.modal-body').append('<p>.append element</p>') : return;
  });
```

Check for existence of the element and then if it doesn't exist, append it.

BTW, where are you clicking? If you're clicking on the detail button, then the reason why the appending happens cumulatively is because you're literally just appending to the previous markup, that already had one `p` tag appended.

A more complete solution would be to use Bootstrap's own functionality and destroy the modal once it's closed:

```
$("#transactionDetailModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
});
```